# Does scikit's cross_val_predict calculates tfidf anew for each fold?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, tf-idf

I have trained a classifier like that:

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),('clf', clf),])  

y_predicted=cross_validation.cross_val_predict(text_clf, X, y, cv=3, n_jobs=3, verbose=2)
```

Since I am using a pipeline object with a tfidf-statistics I wanted to know if the tfidf values get calculated anew for each fold or they are calculated on the whole dataset and the same values are used for each fold.

Comment: *Every* component of the pipeline is calculated anew for each fold.

Comment: How do you know that? Is it mentioned in the docs, because I couldn't find it :(

Comment: I see your point, but even in the documentation some things are considered too elementary to be mentioned *explicitly*; doing the opposite (i.e.calculate tf-idf values in the whole dataset and using this for CV) would completely violate the *core ideas* of both CV and pipelines... I am sure one can confirm that the case is as I say by digging into the source code, but I highly doubt it is worth the fuss...

Comment: That was the reason I asked the question :) I just wanted to be sure that scikit does it the right way . Thank you! Post it as an answer, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Every* component of the pipeline is calculated anew for each fold during cross-validation (CV). Doing the opposite (i.e.calculate tf-idf values in the whole dataset and using these values for the rest of the pipeline components during CV) would completely violate the *core ideas* of both CV and pipelines.

> Is it mentioned in the docs, because I couldn't find it

Indeed it isn't; point is, even in the documentation some things are considered too elementary to be mentioned *explicitly*.